# How to make my function synchronous that has loops in it in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, synchronous

I am doing web scraping on some site using request module. I divided my work into three functions here. First function get the cookie for me, in second functions I get the links from the main pages that I need to visit, and in the third function again I am getting some other pages links from the last links I fetched. Here is my main code:

```
 getCookie(function (header_to_set) {
    getLinksToVisit(header_to_set, function (CoursePageLinks) {
            console.log("Link to visit first: " + CoursePageLinks);
            getAssigmentPages(CoursePageLinks, header_to_set, function (assignment_link_page) {
                console.log("Link to the Assignment: " + assignment_link_page);
                /* Visiting Assignment Page to get the active assignments */


                    request({
                        url: assignment_link_page,
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: header_to_set
                    }, function (errorGettingPage, assignmentPageResponse, assignmentPageHtml) {
                        console.log(assignmentPageResponse.headers);
                        res.send(assignmentPageHtml);
                    })


            });

    })

});
```

Now problem is that when I call my getLinskToVisit() function then it does return me CoursePageLinks but before that getAssignmentPages() functions uses it. I guess this is happening because my getLinksToVisit() is still Asynchronous due to loops in it. Help me in making it Synchronous because I am failed to do that. Here is my getLinksToVisit() code:

```
function getLinksToVisit(headers, callback) {
    let links_to_visit = [];
    console.log(headers);
    request({
        url: "http://someLink",
        headers: headers,
        followRedirect: false,
        method: 'GET',
    }, function (accessPage, getLinksResponse, getLinksHTML) {
        var attributes = [];
        const root = htmlparser.parse(getLinksHTML);
        const parsedData = root.querySelector('#selectNav').querySelectorAll('option');
        for (let i = 0; i < parsedData.length; i++) {
            attributes[i] = parsedData[i].rawAttributes;
        }
        let j = 0;
        for (let l = 0; l < attributes.length; l++) {
            if (attributes[l].value != '""') {
                links_to_visit.push(attributes[l].value);
                j++;
            }
        }
        callback(links_to_visit);
        //console.log(links_to_visit);
        //callback(links_to_visit);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is `getLinksToVisit` supposed to call `callback` twice?

Comment: It doesn't quite makes sense to make an inherently asynchronous function a synchronous one. You are using the request module which performs network IO asynchronously. Can you be a bit more clear as to what you wish to achieve?

Comment: I actually don't see any issue with the implementation since the `getAssigmentPages` should not run till the `callback` is called inside `getLinksToVisit`. Maybe the error you are getting is from something else.

Answer (score 1):

I think its better for you to learn how to work with Async\Await or Promises(which are pretty much the same).
https://javascript.info/async-await - Async \ Await

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise - Promises.

the good old callback ways are pretty old and make things a little bit more messy.